# Nginx vs Cherokee

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver, cherokee

What is the best for 5-10K concurrent connections?
Is someone using Cherokee for huge web applications? (I mean giants like Google, IBM etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I personally tested 4 web servers (Apache 2.2, Cherokee 1.0.15, Lighttpd 1.4.26 and Nginx 0.7.65) and summarized results in this picture.

[Cherokee vs other famous web servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTU6c.png)
[Same as above but different link address](http://www.alobbs.com/images/cherokee1015-keepalive.png)

For the simulation, I used two machines connected by an Ethernet cable. The server machine had a Pentium dual-core CPU T4300 2.10GHz with 4GB RAM, while the client machine used for stressing web servers bore a Pentium M processor 2GHz with 1GB RAM. Both stations had Gigabit Ethernet interface.

The command used to stress-test the web servers was ab and I created a small static file (100 bytes) to prevent network bandwidth bottleneck and to show the performance of web server software instead of the kernel.in

```
ab [-k] -n 10000 -c <concurrency_level> http://<server_IP>/100.html
```

Here, the -k option turns on keepalive, while -n 10000 generates 10,000 HTTP requests and -c sets how many concurrent requests are asked at a time to the target web server.